# SharePoint 2010 SSO with ADFS and Custom STS

Tags: sharepoint, single-sign-on, adfs

I have the following Scenario:

Three different Sharepoint Server: sp1.company.com; sp2.company.com...
Internal Users using Windows Authentication and external users using Forms Based Authentication (FBA).

When the external users change from one server to the other they have to login again. My goal is to have a Single Sign On (SSO) for all the SharePoint Server.

I thought maybe I can do this by using ADFS for the internal users and a customSts (ThinkTecture IdentityServer) for the external users.

Would this be possible? How do I setup the Sts servers ADFS and IdentityServer? Do I have to connect ADFS to IdentityServer over WS-Federation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the architecture you are proposing is fine. You will have to stop using forms auth and windows auth on SharePoint and start using claims-based (SAML and WS-Fed) as the single login mechanism. The architectural pattern is: your applications trust a "federation hub" (that could be either ADFS or Windows Azure Active Directory). That server will have all the trust relationships with your identity providers and applications. In your case, what you have today, is a couple of SharePoint applications and two identity providers (one AD through ADFS and the other a custom database through something like Identity Server).

[image]

Everything is connected through standard protocols and token formats. From SharePoint to the "federation hub" you will use WS-Federation and SAML 1.1 tokens. From the "federation hub" to ADFS you will use WS-Federation and SAML 1.1 or 2.0 tokens. From the "federation hub" to Identity Server it's the same as ADFS. In the future if you want to plug something like Facebook, the "federation hub" needs to speak OAuth, but the SharePoint will still be using WS-Federation, so you don't have to touch that piece.

ADFS as a federation hub will give you support for WS-Federation and SAML protocol (but not OAuth). That might be good enough for you today. You might want to consider [Windows Azure Active Directory](http://acs.codeplex.com/) (previously known as Windows Azure Access Control Service) which is a "federation hub" that is offered as a service from Microsoft (with a price tag of 2 USD per 100K login). Microsoft is currently more focused on WAAD other than ADFS. WAAD will give you support for OAuth, mobile scenarios, Office 365, etc. Not saying that ADFS is being retired or anything like that, simply my point of view of where the investments are being made.

Putting things together requires some learning and time, so be prepared to hit some walls like certificate issues, miss-configurations, home realm discovery, claims transformation, SharePoint people picker, cookies, logout, etc.

Here are some pointers:

- Adding IdentityServer as a Claims Provider to ADFS is simple, you have to use the FederationMetadata endpoint provided by IdentityServer and add it as a Claims Provider in ADFS (Wizard or PowerShell).
- [Configuring SharePoint 2010 with ADFS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx)
- [Setting up ADFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/moss_attacks/archive/2012/03/20/zen-and-the-art-of-adfs-implementation-part-1-of-5-introduction.aspx)
- [Configuring SharePoint 2010 with Windows Azure AD to use Google and ADFS identities using Auth10 in 5 minutes](http://blog.auth10.com/2012/07/04/configuring-sharepoint-2010-to-accept-google-and-adfs-identities/). This last one belong to the product we are building that aims to simplify all these :)

Matias

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, that helped me a lot.

I managed to build a simple ASP App that uses ADFS and CustomSTS to authenticate. I could select the home realm in ADFS and could log me in in IdentityServer but wasn't redirected back to my App. Further I didn't manage it to do it with SharePoint. It should be easy with the PowerShell Scripts, but it not worked yet.

About the People Picker: I know I have to overwrite the ClaimsProvider in SharePoint. Do I have to query against AD and my Custom Membership Provider?

I looked into your product. Maybe this could be usefull for us too. I will test it further.

regards,
Patrik

Comment: The default experience of the people picker in SharePoint 2010 will be allowing you to enter any string. Since now you are using claims, you can say "allow access to this document library if user has a claimtype=email with claimvalue=john@foo.com. If you want a better experience for the people picker an option is to create your own claims provider that will allow you to search on the repositories (DB and AD in your case). If you are interested in Auth10, get in touch with us at "support at auth10 com", we are running an early adoption program and looking for feedback and real world usage.